# How to put React hooks into for loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I want append a div container with divs. The divs quantity is the data json's length. I have tried to put the hooks inside the for loop, but it throwed error.

The project's github link:
https://github.com/folza1/react-modulzaro

```
import "./App.css";
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

function App() {
  var data = require("./data.json");

  //for(let i=0;i<data.length;i++{WHAT COPY HERE TO APPEND THE 30 divProduct?})

  const container = useRef(null);

  const divProduct = document.createElement("div");
  divProduct.classList.add("divStyle");

  useEffect(() => {
    container.current.appendChild(divProduct);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div id={"container"} ref={container} />
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Just use `Array.map` then ? Why do you need refs and `useEffect` ?

Comment: Consider moving the require outside the app component, and don't use dom methods inside react components? The useEffect seems unnecessary. Why not render what you want rather than mutate the dom.

Comment: Whatever this code is trying to do, it seems like a drastically over-engineered way to do it.  Do you just want to `.map()` over your array in the JSX to output elements?

Comment: Does this help? https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/rendering-lists

Comment: Recommended reading: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example code posted seems somewhat confused with regards to how React works.

Assuming `data` is an array of objects, all you would need for this is something like the following:

```
import "./App.css";
import * as React from "react";

const data = [
  {id: "1", name: "obj1"}, 
  {id: "2", name: "obj2"},
  {id: "3", name: "obj3"}
];

function App() {
  return (
    <div id="container">
      {data.map(obj => <p key={obj.id}>{obj.name}</p>)}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```